# Why i cant use a <hr/> tag outside another tag in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When trying to return this code:

```
return <hr/><h1>E esse é um Class Component</h1>
```

I get a error, but if i change to:

```
return <h1><hr/>E esse é um Class Component</h1>
```

It works. In the error it says Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment but i didn't quite get it. Can someone explain please? I'm starting to learn React so i'm kinda newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, it's like you tried to send a return value as `return ({item: 1}, {item: 2});`. That's even not valid for a function return value, though.

JSX children work the same as a Javascript's function return value. Also, in functions, you need to return only a type of value, like object, string etc.

That transpiles in background:

```
function MyElement()
{
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
}
```

To this:

```
function MyElement()
{
  return React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello World');
}
```

In background, the below example returns an object for the div. And its children contains an array which has only an element inside it as `ReturnElement`:

```
<div>
   <ReturnElement />
</div>
```

The div element is scope for return element. On the other hand, if you want to return clear scope for your DOM tree, it's better to use the React Fragments.

```
<>
  <ReturnChildElement />
</>
```

Or, you might want to use that syntax if you need to pass a key to Fragment;

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>
  <ReturnChildElement />
</React.Fragment>
```

**Note:** If you want to use the above first JSX fragment syntax, your babel version minimum must be at least "v7.0.0-beta.31".

Also, you can check out the fragments on React's Official Docs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement should either return one enclosing tag or a fragment.

Change this line

```
return
  <hr/>
    <h1>E esse é um Class Component</h1>
```

to

```
return
  <>
    <hr/>
    <h1>E esse é um Class Component</h1>
  </>
```